# Font consistency in a textarea

Tags: html, css, fonts, textarea

How do I make a textarea have the same font as everything else on the webpage?

Currently I have my code:

`test.html`:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
      </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testarea">
          <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

`test.css`:

```
    body { font: 100%/120% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
    #testarea textarea { width: 30em;height: 7em;font: inherit;}
```

Font inherits in Mozilla, but IE7 keeps Courier inside the textarea.

UPD: Apparently `inherit` does not work in IE for textarea, so I'll go with AlbertoPL's method.

Comment: Strange that Mozilla "works" as I came searching for this bug when it didn't (FF 4). My `body` has the font declaration, yet the `textarea` was in courier. Specifying my font delcaration as `body, textarea { ...` worked fine.

Comment: ... even better, I actually read the question and set `textarea { font:inherit}` which also works well ;).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Simply create a textarea element and define your font element there.

```
textarea { font: 100%/120% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
```

you can move it out of the body element.

You'll have to define the font twice (once in body and once in textarea) if you don't want to use `*`.

Comment: That'd work, but there's apparently a fair amount of overhead involved   in applying a style to everything via *

Comment: Defining font twice will also definitely work, but why won't font: inherit work? Like I said, I can't test atm, but I'm 99% certain that's not what I did...

Comment: I'm going to guess that IE7 simply does not inherit correctly, which is a shame.

Comment: Eric Meyer removed the 'inherit' values from his famous CSS reset after realizing that IE does not support it properly http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/01/15/resetting-again/